# Importing serverless-http error - Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Im using AWS with ***Serverless Framework v1.36.3 with TypeScript.*** Today when I make a deploy the whole API/Lambdas was affected, and in my IDE I see some issue from tslint:

[image]

The problem is the way to importing ***serverless-http v1.9.1*** using:

```
`import * as serverless from "serverless-http";`.
```

When I call `serverless(api.app)` it come with that error:

> TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
>   Type 'typeof import("node_modules/serverless-htt...' has no compatible
>   call signatures.

**To Fix** it I changed the import and it work again:

```
 const serverless = require('serverless-http');
```

What is the difference between `import * as serverless from "serverless-http";` **and** `const serverless = require('serverless-http');`

I always I use `import * as serverless from "serverless-http";` I the error appear in the ***serverless-http v1.9.1***.

Thanks in advances.

Comment: Check https://dzone.com/articles/import-statements-in-typescript-which-syntax-to-us, has a superb explanation of different import types.

Comment: @diosney Thk, But why was that working almost a year and now it was that he gave the error?

Comment: Maybe they changed the exported surface area.